# Cannot find Visual Studio 2013 Diagnostic Tools?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop, and under the DEBUG tab, I cannot find the diagnostic tools, I tried to press alt+f12, nothing comes out.

Shall I download it from somewhere and install it as an update? I googled very hard, but cannot find such a download...

Comment: Not very clear what you are talking about, the only "Diagnostic Tools" menu entry I know about is the one that was added to VS2015.  Consider updating.

Comment: You mean graphics diagnostics? `DEBUG->Graphics->Start Diagnostics`?